# Expire date with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide div when current time equals the time from JSON file. But I can't find the right approach. You can play with data by using this converter: http://www.epochconverter.com/

And my code:

```js
function Ctrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.events = [ {
  "start_date" : "1288323623006",
  "team1" : "FC Dynamo Kiev",
  "team2" : "FC Shahtar Donetsk",
  "tournaments" : [ {
    "tournament_id" : "1"
  } ]
}, {
  "start_date" : "1416844143000",
  "team1" : "FC Dynamo Kiev123",
  "team2" : "FC Shahtar Donetsk",
  "tournaments" : [ {
    "tournament_id" : "1"
  } ]
} ];

  //Real time clock
    $scope.clock = "loading clock..."; // initialise the time variable
    $scope.tickInterval = 1000; //ms

    var tick = function() {
        $scope.clock = Date.now() // get the current time
        $timeout(tick, $scope.tickInterval); // reset the timer
    };

    // Start the timer
    $timeout(tick, $scope.tickInterval);

    $scope.$watch('clock', function (newVal) {
      $scope.clock = newVal;
      console.log(newVal);
    });
  
}
```

```css
</style> <!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue: http://goo.gl/BUfGZ --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
```

```html
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">    
<div ng-repeat="event in events" ng-hide="event.start_date == clock">
        <h2>{{event.team1}} vs {{event.team2}}</h2>
        <p>Starts in: {{event.start_date | date: 'shortTime'}}; Current time: {{clock | date: 'shortTime'}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try using < instead of equality, the time might have passed but is not equal to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as == will look for number equality, the time might have passed and your clock was never == to the date.

Try if the time has passed rather than time equality with < or >

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events" ng-hide="event.start_date < clock">
```